# Outlook 2016 for Mac Export Broken?

Tags: macos, backup, email, software-recommendation, ms-office

I run an online tech-support system. My Outlook 2016 for Mac is very slow in response & when I asked for advice on the issue, my friend asked me to clean up my mailboxes. However, I cannot do that because I have hundreds of emails that are important. So I tried to export the email database. But somehow the export is not working. It crashes after 3-4%. How can I fix this or is there other ways to backup Outlook 2016 for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding you outlook mac identity? If you haven't, then have a go through that and try exporting your email database again. This is a manual process and may acquire your attention as well as your time.

Have a look here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_for_mac_support_team_blog/2015/01/07/outlook-for-mac-for-office-365-database/

If you are seeking an automatic process then you can have a look here: http://www.mailbackupx.com/how-to-scenerios/how-to-backup-outlook-mac-mails-on-mac.html

Comment: I think I will use the software, as I need some quick solution. Thanks for the answer.